# Dropdown menu to filter view

Tags: views

I am creating a document library. I've made a custom content type of "document" and a taxonomy for document categories. I've added the categories as a field in the document view. I want to display the document list, and at the top, have a dropdown menu where you can choose a category, and then have the view update to show you just the documents in that category.

I know that you can create a filter and then "expose" that filter to the user, but when I do that with this example, it makes a text entry box, not a dropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

You can give drop down menu using **Filter Criteria** option.

In **Filter Criteria** in the field which you added for filtering Check the **checkbox** called

> Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you give a try to [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu). It is a very flexible dropdown menu that basically works with any types of blocks. So you can build any View (block) or Taxonomy block or whatever and have it available for inclusion in OM Maximenu. THe toughest part seems to be skinning and styling and providing the right kind of markup.

Comment: That looks interesting, but it looks like more of a navigation menu replacement. I just want a simple form-based dropdown to filter a view. I know you can make a filter and then "expose" it, but when I do it it creates a text box you need to type into, not a dropdown.

Comment: Ouch, sorry, I completely misunderstood you question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Start using Views 3. For taxonomies you have the following option.

[image]